# Can't access router's IP address on certain PC but can another PC

Tags: networking, router

So I have 2 computers connected to a router.

On one PC (which I just upgraded the motherboard on), I could no longer access the router’s web management page via the router’s IP Address. I have internet but can’t access the router or any device in my LAN.

On the other PC I could. I also tried using my laptop connected via Wi-Fi and I could access it.

Edit:
Using Windows 7 on both.
MAC filtering is disabled.

Comment: What is the IP configuration of the PC? Also, network cards are usually integrated onto the motherboard, so changing the motherboard changes your MAC address. Do you have some restrictions on the router's management page, like IP address range or MAC address restriction?

Comment: Just checked no IP address range or MAC address filtering on the router.

Comment: Check your browser's proxy. Make sure that everything is unchecked in Connection Settings

Comment: Checked browser settings does not seem to be the case. Tried with IE, Firefox and Chrome. Also tried my WD My Cloud could not detect it.

Answer (score 0):

So Found the culprit.
My New mother board was the MSI Z97 Gaming 5 and along with the LAN Driver was the Killer Network Manager Utility. When I disabled Bandwidth Control I was able to access my other devices.
Still looking for the a way to enable bandwidth control while allowing me to access other devices on my LAN though but anyway disabling it solves the issue.